# Bash: How to dynamically pad spaces as per the max column size

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Below will be output from bash script. I have more than 10 columns and don't want to waste space. I am dynamically calculating the max length of entries in every column and storing it. Now I want to use this max length for dynamically pad spaces to each column.

```
|No.           |IPAddress     |Link Speed        
|1             |20.0.2.134    |4.0           
|2             |20.0.2.136    |1.0
```

code:

```
# Collect the max size of each column and stored in col_length
declare -a col_length
for (( col=1; col<=$(head -n1 $tmp_file | awk -F '::' '{print NF}'); col++ ));
do
    length=$(get_column_size "$col")
    col_length+=($col $length)
done

#Print with formatting
cat $tmp_file | while read line 
do
   echo $line | awk -F'::' '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        printf "|%-14s", $i}; 
    }'
   printf "\n"
done
```

Currently I am using %-14s, but I want it to be dynamically provided. For e.g., for first column, I don't need 14 space padding.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output as right now we're all just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Since all we know so far about your expected output is that you "don't want to waste space" - with a version of `column` that has the `-o` argument to specify the output separator (e.g. column from util-linux 2.33.1) the following will waste no space:

```
$ sed 's/ *|/|/g' file | column -s'|' -o'|' -t
|No.|IPAddress |Link Speed
|1  |20.0.2.134|4.0
|2  |20.0.2.136|1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do all this with just one `awk` invocation:

```bash
awk -F '::' 'NR==1 {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) len[i]=length($i)}
  {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "|%-" len[i] "s", $i; printf "\n"}' "$tmp_file"
```

Note that GNU `awk` supports the `*` format modifier:

```bash
awk -F '::' 'NR==1 {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) len[i]=length($i)}
  {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "|%-*s", len[i], $i; printf "\n"}' "$tmp_file"
```

Comment: note that basically **every** major `awk` variant in use today supports the `*` format modifier :: :::::: ::::: `date | nawk '($3 = sprintf("%-*s", 17, $3))'` ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: :::::::: `Thu Dec 15                 06:50:21 EST 2022`.  ::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: ::::: :: ::::::: `date | mawk '($3 = sprintf("%-*s", 17, $3))'` ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: ::::::: `Thu Dec 15                  06:50:16 EST 2022`

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without the pipe symbols in the output:

```
sed -E 's/ +//g' $tmp.file | column -s '|' -t 
No.  IPAddress   LinkSpeed
1    20.0.2.134  4.0
2    20.0.2.136  1.0
```